# How to create image as background-image for all screen sizes

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

How do I create an image for all the screen sizes like iphone 5 to 6\6+ (same as 7\7+) ?

here the confusion,do I create one or I create A FEW base images?

I read about the @1x, @2x, @3x. But I am still confused.

```
                     iphone4    iphone5        iphone6        phone6+

 Canvas Size(pts)    320x460    320x568        375x667        414x736
 Screen Size(Px)     640x960    640 x1136      750x1334       1080x1920
```

here the approaches i will use, please help me to rectify them.

This is what I will do base on the screen size of each iphone.

Approach (A):

1.0) create only ONE base image of size 320x568 ( base on iphone 5 )

1.1) name this image : myimage320x568.png , myimage320x568@2x.png, myimage320x568@3x.png

is the the correct way? Will system scale the image correctly for iphone5/6/6+?

Approach (B)

1. Create an image of 320x568 for iphone5
     name it. myimage320x568.png
2. create an image of 375x667 for iphone6

   name it myimage375x667.png ,make a copy and name it  myimage375x667@2x.png
3. create an image of 414x736 for iphone6+

   name it myimage414x736.png ,myimage414x736@3x.png

   4) use code to detect iphone model or screen.height

   ```
    if ( iphone5 ){

      use myimage320x568.png

    } else if (iphone 6 or 7) {

        use myimage375x667.png

   } else if (iphone 6+ or 7+) {

       use myImage414x736.png

   }
   ```

is this correct?

//-- Update

This works. But I am not sure what is the base Image size should use?

use this 375x667 (iphone6) or this size   414x736 (iphone 6+) as the base image

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size)

let img = UIImage(named: "iosWPMain1")

img?.draw(in: self.view.bounds, blendMode: .normal, alpha: 1)

let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!

UIGraphicsEndImageContext()


self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi, I believe you are not making this image using CoreGraphics. Can you please clarify?. If you are not making this image inside app, then please check my answer and let me know if you have any doubts :).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an image for all the screen sizes if you want to use it to cover the whole screen and does not crop or distort. So you should use approach B.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding external image, then I suggest you to use `ImageAssets.xcassets`. Add your images there. This way, when you call the `UIImage` using `UIImage(named: "image")`. This way when you release your app in AppStore, iOS will only download the images required for the particular device.

Also, you can get the scale-factor of a device using the following code

```
let scale: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.scale
```

This way, you can change your logic to this:

```
let scaleFactor: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.scale

if scaleFactor == 1.0 {
   // use 1x image
}else if scaleFactor == 2.0 {
   // use 2x image
}else if scaleFactor == 3.0 {
   // use 3x image
}
```

But, it's better to use `ImageAssets.xcassets` than this. By following this approach, your app size will increase.

Comment: 1.0 for non-retina ( iphone4) , 2.0 for retina (iphone 5,5s,6,6s) , 3.0 for retina iphone 6+, 7+ .If this is the case, I use Ashley (above) approach with UIGraphic to draw base on your approach to detect : Create a large image base on iphone6+ point size and draw base on the view.frame.size and assign the image to view.background = UIColor(patternImage: image) is this ok??

Comment: So, you are drawing image using CoreGraphics right. Then you don't need to consider all of this. Just before beginning the context using this, `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: 100, height: 100), false, UIScreen.main.scale)`, you can simply set the scale

Comment: I update my code above. I dont understand why use w:100, H: 100 .

Comment: @MilkBottle, please use the base size. w:100, H:100 is for example.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to create a single image at the largest size, and then set your `UIImageView`'s `contentMode` to `.aspectFill`